Adding Subform fields to approval summary in zoho creator
I am creating an e-procurement application on zoho creator.When a material request is submitted.It should be directed to manager for approval. In the approval summary, I am not able to see the product and quantity details because both are in subform of  material request form.
In approval workflow properties, I am able to add other fields of material request form but not subform fields. Product and quantity are two of the most important details manager should know before accepting or rejecting the proposal.
Is there any way to add subform fields to approval summary?
If anyone could help me solve this, it would be really helpful!
Thanks in advance!

Okay, I found out that you can't add sub form fields into approval summary(the feature is not available yet in zoho creator).So I created a rich text field and copied the information I need from subform to rich text field.
